# My programm doesn't return anything when I compile and I cant find the error. It seems to be that the code is fine

Tags: arrays, c

My programme does compile so there is no bug but there is certainly a mistake cause is returns nothing.

I expected to return the minimum value of the initialized board.  The codes seems to me right but I don't get the result I want.  The whole point is to find the minimum number of an `int` initialized board

```
#include<stdio.h>

int find(int board[]);

int main (){
    int board[6] = {6, 2, 6, 99, 0, 2};
    find(board[6]); //call

    printf(" %d",find(board[6]));
    return 0;
}

int find(int board[]){
    int minimum = board[0]; //initialize the first cell as the minimum one

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        if(minimum > board[i]) minimum = board[i];
        printf("%d",minimum);
    }

    return minimum;
}
```

Comment: `find(board[6]);` is passing the integer that is one past the end of the array. You should receive a compiler warning for this. Use `find(board);` instead. You generally also want to pass the length of the array to a function since there is no way to determine that inside the function. This may not be the only issue.

Comment: "My programme does compile so there is no bug". There is, please enable compiler warnings – *warning C4047: 'function': 'int *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'*. Also, you unnecessarily call `find()` twice.

Comment: Many programs that compile cleanly do have "one more bug", because most bugs are logical errors or oversights, not syntactical. There is no excuse for a running a program where the compiler *tells* you about it.

Comment: Bugs only happen in compiled programs. If it does not compile, then it is an error - unless you are treating warnings as errors.

Comment: So we still don't have a canonical for attempts of using `array[n]` to pass a whole array yet? This kind of question appears every now and then.

Comment: ALWAYS enable your compiler's warnings. With gcc, I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. It finds three errors.

Answer (score 1):

Some parts of the code require modification:

- When an array is declared as `board[6]`, the name of the array is `board` instead of `board[6]`. Thus, when passing the array into a function, we should use `board` as the argument.
- If we want to use the return value of a function, we should assign the return value to a variable so that we can use it later.

A modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int find(int board[]);

int main() {
    int board[6] = {7, 5, 8, 2, 4, 1};
    int minimum = find(board);
    printf("%d\n", minimum);
    return 0;
}

int find(int board[]){
    int minimum = board[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", minimum);
        if (minimum > board[i]) {
            minimum = board[i];
        }
    }
    return minimum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int find(int board[]);

int main (){
    int board[6] = {6, 2, 6, 99, 0, 2};
    find(board[6]); //call
```

at least you should have received a warning here, as you define `find()` function as a function receiving an array of six integers as parameter and you pass an integer (`board[6]` is just the element past the last element of the array, something that you cannot use at all, as the elements of the `board` array go from index 0 to index 5, for a total of 6 elements)  You should have definied `find()` indicating the array to be used, how large is that array (the number of elements it has, as this will not be known to the function if you only pass the array reference) and the value you want to search, as in:

```
int find(int array[], size_t array_len, int value_to_search)
{
    /* blah blah */
    return /* the index of the found element */;
}
```

and, in `main()` use it as:

```
    int found = find(board, 6, 99);  /* search array board, of six elements
                                      * for element whose value is 99
                                      * and return the index at which
                                      * it was found, or BAD in case
                                      * that element was not found */
    if (found == BAD) { /* BAD should be a constant you will never produce, like -1 or the size of the array, as that number will never be accessible */
         /* blah blah error */
        return 1;
    }
    printf("element 99 was found at position %d in array board\n", found);
    return 0;
}
```

---

In your case, as you search the list, the correct approach would have been to write the following `find()`:

```
#define BAD (-1)

int find(int array[], size_t array_len, int value_to_search)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < array_len; i++)
         if (array[i] == value_to_search)
             return i;
    /* if we get here, we have not found it */
    return BAD;
} /* find */
```

then, in main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int find(int board[], size_t board_size, int to_search);

int main()
{
      int board[6] = {6, 2, 6, 99, 0, 2};
      int found = find(board, 6, 99);
      int to_search[3] = {99, 6, 100};

      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         int found = find(board, 6, to_search[i]);
         if (found == BAD) {
             printf("value %d not found in array\n", to_search[i]);
         } else { /* found */
             printf("value %d found at position %d\n",
                     to_search[i], found);
         }
      }
      return 0;
} /* main */
```

which will produce:

```
$ a.out
value 99 found at position 3
value 6 found at position 0
value 100 not found in array
```